# Geometrical interpretation of second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

What is the geometrical interpretation of the second fundamental form?

Let $N\subset M$ be a hypersurface and locally orient it with normal field $n$. I heard from my professor that if the 2nd fundamental form is strictly positive w.r.t. $n$, then it implies geodesical convexity, i.e. if I connect two neighboring points in $N$ with a geodesic of $M$, then the geodesic curves to the direction of $n$.

For example if $M=B^2(0, 1)$, $N=S_r=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=r\}, r\in]0,1[$, and I choose the inner normal field for $S_r$, then any geodesic connecting two points of $S_r$ lies completely in $B(0, r)$ except the endpoints. My question is: is this true and why? I only know this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Richard_Bishop3/publication/282574798_InfinitesimaIl_Convexity_Implies_Local_Convexity/links/5612965a08ae83674f4389c3.pdf?origin=publication_list), which says that infinitesimal convexity implies local convexity, i.e. N "lies on one side" with respect to the image of sufficiently small neighborhood under $\exp$.

Answer (score 4):

The second fundamental form is measuring how the surface patch $\sigma(U):=V$, bends with respect to the surface normal of $V$ after a small perturbation in the domain $U$ of $\sigma$. In order to do this you measure the quantity,

$$\big(\sigma(u + \Delta u, v+ \Delta v) - \sigma(u,v) \big) \cdot \textbf{N}$$

where $\textbf{N}$ is the normal field on $V$.

[image]

You can use Taylor's theorem to approximate $\sigma(u + \Delta u, v+ \Delta v) - \sigma(u,v)$ and that is how the second fundamental form for surfaces arises.

Comment: This works fine for a surface in $\Bbb R^3$, but not so well for a submanifold of an abstract Riemannian manifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin. It was not clear to me that the OP knew about the geometric interpretation of the second fundamental form even in this special case. If this knowledge is already known and the OP acknowledges that, I'll make an edit or you can elaborate. Also, if you click that link, they author's proof proceeds with the case when $n=2$, so what I present is actually not so special and should be right on point with what the OP needs.